# How to format drive with partitions

Tags: hard-drive, format

I have a drive with 3 partitions - Vista, Ubuntu and just storage. I'm used to creating and formatting partitions.

However, I have never formatted a entire drive with partitions. Any pointers to resources would be great.

Again I wish to format the entire drive removing the partitions.

**EDIT:** The Vista parition is corrupt and not recoverable.

Comment: A little more information is that the Vista partition is corrupt and not recoverable. So I need to fully format it.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you're using to format it, but in most cases

1. Delete the old partitions in your favorite drive management tool -- Windows' Disk Management console, or GParted, etc.
2. Create new partitions as desired.
3. Format the new partitions with whatever filesystems are needed.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to erase the entire drive and remove the partition table, you can just use [DBAN](http://www.dban.org/) over it.

If you want to keep the partitions but format each as a specific file system, [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) can help you with that.

If you plan on instantly installing a new OS to the entire drive, most OS installers will allow you to select the **entire drive** as the target, and they will get rid of the partitions before installing.

Comment: dban takes a while - just deleting the partitions should be sufficient IMHO

Comment: Yes but he hasn't indicated his intentions with the disk. If he's formatting it because he's getting rid of it, I'd DBAN it.

Answer (score 1):

> [EASEUS Partition Master Home Edition](http://www.partition-tool.com/download.htm) is a FREE ALL-IN-ONE partition solution and disk management utility. It allows you to extend partition (especially for system drive), manage disk space easily, settle low disk space problem under Windows 2000/XP/Vista/Windows 7 (Only for 32 bit, figure out Windows 32 bit or 64 bit). The most popular hard disk management functions are brought together with powerful data protection including: Partition Manager, Partition Recovery Wizard and Disk & Partition Copy Wizard.
>   Top Benefits:
>   FREE FOR HOME USERS. No Adware and Toolbar.
>   Extend system partition to maximize computer performance.
>   Partition Manager utility for better hard disk management and computer performance maximization.
>   New!    Partition Recovery Wizard to perform PC disaster recovery to save data.
>   Copy Wizard to copy partition or migrate entire hard disk to another without Windows system reinstallation.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **[Active@ Kill Disk](http://www.killdisk.com/)**, it will take care of it and delete all partitions on the drive.

*Active@ Kill Disk is freeware.*